# Changing bibliography style

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing my CV using markdown and want to have multiple bibliography sections (one for journal articles, another for book chapters etc). I'm using the `RefManagerR` package to do this and it works nicely.

```
library("RefManageR")
BIB <- structure(list(structure(list(title = "Quantitative palaeotemperature records inferred from fossil pollen and chironomid assemblages from Lake Gilltjarnen, northern central Sweden", author = structure(list(structure(list(given = "K", family = "Antonsson", role = NULL, email = NULL, comment = NULL), .Names = c("given", "family", "role", "email", "comment")), structure(list(given = "SJ", family = "Brooks", role = NULL, email = NULL, comment = NULL), .Names = c("given", "family", "role", "email", "comment")), structure(list(given = "H", family = "Seppa", role = NULL, email = NULL, comment = NULL), .Names = c("given", "family", "role", "email", "comment"))), class = "person"), journal = "Journal of Quaternary Science", year = "2006", number = "8", pages = "831-841", volume = "21"), .Names = c("title", "author", "journal", "year", "number", "pages", "volume"), bibtype = "Article", key = "RID:0428130725771-5", dateobj = structure(1136070000, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", day.mon = 0L))), strings = structure(character(0), .Names = character(0)), class = c("BibEntry", "bibentry"))

NoCite(BIB)
PrintBibliography(BIB, .opts = list(style = "latex", bib.style = "authoryear", 
                                    sorting = "ydnt"))
```

Which is rendered in the pdf as

> Antonsson, K, S. Brooks and H. Seppa (2006). “Quantitative palaeotemperature records inferred from fossil pollen and chironomid assemblages from Lake Gilltjarnen, northern central Sweden”. In: *Journal of Quaternary Science* 21.8, pp. 831-841.

I want to change the style of the reference. Basically, I want to remove the quote marks and the `In:`, and put initials after the name. I understand that the style is set using `tools::bibstyle` and that I need to make a routine called `formatArticle` but the example for `tools::bibstyle` only shows how to change the sort order and I cannot work out how to see the default JSS style.

Please can someone show me how to use `bibstyle`.

Alternatively, please can someone show me how to make multiple bibliography sections in a single document using the bibliography generator built into rmarkdown, so I can use a csl file.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no option yet when working with RefManageR. Raising the flexibility of using bibstyles is in the pipeline though.

Comment: Do you intend to use output formats other than `pdf`? If not, you can use `latex` directly to achieve what you want,  though you'll need to *Tame the BeaST* and from personal experience, it isn't much fun.

Answer (score 1):

Answering only the part about bibliography in multiple sections:
If you want to do it "using the bibliography generator built into rmarkdown", you will need to change the the latex template used for generating the pdf from the Rmarkdown file. Set the template at the YAML section with something like:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: mytemplate.tex
```

There are [references](http://svmiller.com/blog/2016/02/svm-r-markdown-manuscript/) on how to work with templates.

An easier approach would be to add the multiple sections in the RMarkdown file itself, and print out the bibs. Example of an `.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "2 bibs"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r init, echo=FALSE}
library("RefManageR")

## loading some bib entries from example file
file <- system.file("Bib", "biblatexExamples.bib", package = "RefManageR")
BibOptions(check.entries = FALSE)
bib <- ReadBib(file)

## Gerating the entries for the 2 sections
bib1 = bib[[5:6]]
bib2 = bib[[7:8]]
```

Intro text.

# Bib 1

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
NoCite(bib1)
PrintBibliography(bib1, .opts = list(style = "markdown", bib.style = "authoryear", sorting = "ydnt"))
```

# Bib 2

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
NoCite(bib2)
PrintBibliography(bib2, .opts = list(style = "markdown", bib.style = "authoryear", sorting = "ydnt"))
```
````